# Is this `img` creator decently secure from XSS?

Tags: javascript, parsing, security, regex

This is being used now, seems decent to me but I'm curious.

```
    if (m=s.match(/^\s*(https?:\/\/[^\s<>"]+)\.(bmp|png|webp|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg)\s*$/)) { 
         // example s: http://mustachify.me/?src=http://www.someImage.jpg
        return '<img src="'+m[1]+'.'+m[2]+'">';
    }
    if (m=s.match(/^\s*(https?:\/\/[^\s<>?"]+)\.(bmp|png|webp|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg)(\?[^\s<>?"]*)?\s*$/)) {
        // example s: http://place.com/photo/something.jpg?height=600&modified_at=1384796271&ratio_x=03&ratio_y=02&width=900
        return '<img src="'+m[1]+'.'+m[2]+(m[3]||'')+'">';
    }
```

I've been trying to get around it but haven't yet managed it. So I'm thinking of just using this.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to code review. You might get a better review if you include a little more context in your question.

Comment: @ckuhn203 hmm. What more could I include? This shows the regex, splits them and recombines them. You can test it in the console by simply copy/pasting and looking at the string returned. Someone who is good with XSS techniques won't have trouble understanding

Comment: You've posted two snippets with very little context about what you're trying to do. Adding more of the surrounding code and/or more explanation of what you're trying to accomplish generally leads to a more thorough review. (and a better learning experience)

Comment: @ckuhn203 I'm sorry bud, but this is exactly what you need. Will that regex/return succumb to XSS is the only question. Can't you read the code?

Comment: Clearly S = one of the examples. Then it is split using the `match`, the value is then returns wrapped in the img tag. There's nothing else to explain. If you can't tell what I'm asking from this you are definitely not the guy to answer.

Answer (score 3):

The part of your code shown here does not look like it's vulnerable to XSS, but it could be cleaner. You seem to be doing 3 separate things:

- Ensuring that a URI looks like a path to an image.
- Ensuring that a URI doesn't contain certain characters like quotes and angle brackets.
- Trimming whitespace from the ends of a URI.

Doing those things in discreet steps would be cleaner. If you trim the string first, you won't need to look at the match results, only check whether there was a match. That means you can avoid the poor style used in the construct `if (m=foo)` without having to rewrite that part, and you can eliminate redundancy.

You could use `encodeURI` instead of throwing out URIs with certain characters; this way the user doesn't have to encode those characters before passing you the string.

```
s = s.trim();
if (s.match(/^https?:\/\/.*?\.(bmp|png|webp|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg)(\?.*)?$/)) {
    // looks like a path to an image
    return '<img src="' + encodeURI(s) + '">';
}
```

If you are doing this on the client, consider creating an image element and returning that instead of returning a string.

```
s = s.trim();
if (s.match(/^https?:\/\/.*?\.(bmp|png|webp|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg)(\?.*)?$/)) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = encodeURI(s);
    return img;
}
```

Also, the regular expressions you are using and the one in this example will match things like `http://lol.jpg`; you may want to consider making it more strict.